# Android Webview app crashes after selecting Contact with Contact picker

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, webview, xamarin.android

I have a Mono Android Webview app (developed with c# VS2015).

The issue I am facing at the moment, is that I am starting an ActionPick Intent to choose a contact in order to send a custom SMS. But once I select the contact from the list I am getting an "Object not set to an instance of an object" exception somehow in my OnActivityResult method.

The important thing here is that I am calling this intent from a Javascript Interface class (this is how I am sending data from my website, inside the webview to my app). I'm guessing this has something to do with it, but I am at a loss, as I have try/catch blocks around everything and yet the app is still giving me "MyApp has stopped working" messages.

It's calling the MainActivity ContactSMS() just fine, and bringing up the contact list.. I just seem to be handling the result of selecting a contact incorrectly.

Thank you very much for any help/suggestions!

Javascript Interface:

```
[JavascriptInterface, Export("contactsms")]
        public void ContactSMS()
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.GetType() == typeof(MainActivity))
                    ((MainActivity)context).ContactSMS();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Interceptor_ContactSMS: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

MainActivity:

```
public void ContactSMS()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a new intent for choosing a contact
                var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
                //contactPickerIntent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);

                //Start the contact picker expecting a result
                // with the resultCode '101'                
                StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, 101);                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(instance.context, "MainActivity_ContactSMS: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

OnActivityResult (**This doesn't run - crashes before entering method**):

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            try
            {                
                //See if we are handling the contact picker request code
                //  and that the result code is ok!
                if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                  ...
                }
```

Logcat from app crash:
02-20 16:32:33.824  7348  7348 I MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

02-20 16:32:33.846  7348  7348 I MonoDroid: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

02-20 16:32:33.846  7348  7348 I MonoDroid:   at MyApp.MainActivity.OnActivityResult (Int32 requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) <0xdd295de8 + 0x00a64> in :0

02-20 16:32:33.846  7348  7348 I MonoDroid:   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnActivityResult_IILandroid_content_Intent_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, Int32 requestCode, Int32 native_resultCode, IntPtr native_data) <0xdd295c80 + 0x00083> in :0

02-20 16:32:33.846  7348  7348 I MonoDroid:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:f36adbb7-bad7-46f4-8e5c-eab3c45d9499 (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr)

02-20 16:32:33.862  7348  7348 W art     : JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable

02-20 16:32:33.868  7348  7348 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: Your code works fine by my side, the problem is not related to calling this intent from a Javascript Interface class, I think something went wrong in your `OnActivityResult`, have you tried to comment all code in this `OnActivityResult` and see if it works? If works, please show us your whole code of `OnActivityResult`.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to get back to this. You were right, there was a null reference that, for some reason, wasn't being handled by my try/catch.